# jQuery slideDown() with append(): Outermost<div> works ok but inside content not

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to `append()` and `slideDown()` a div which (supposedly) wraps around a couple of elements. I'd like the `<div>` *along with* its contents to slide down. But from what I've got, only the `<div>` slides down like I want(that's why I put a solid border around it)

Here's teh code:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#check').click(function() {
        $("body").append('<div class="mydiv" style="border-style:solid;overflow:auto;height:700px"><b><label style="position: absolute; left: 476px; font-size: 22px; top: 250px;">Order Information</label><div class="detailz">Name<br><br>E-mail<br><br><br>Shipping address<br><br><br><br>State<br><br>Phone<br><br>Credit/Debit Card No.</div><form name="orderdetails" action="www.google.com" method="post"><p><span class="detailz"><input name="name" style="position: absolute; left: 271px; top: 15px; width: 229px; height: 28px;" type="text"></span><span class="detailz"><input name="email" type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 273px; top: 70px; width: 229px; height: 27px;"></span></p><p><span class="detailz"><textarea name="address" cols="" rows="" id="add" style="position: absolute; resize: none; left: 273px; top: 139px; width: 244px; height: 103px;"></textarea><select name="state" style="position: absolute; left: 276px; top: 271px; width: 233px;"><option>Andaman and Nicobar</option><option>Andhra Pradesh</option><option>Assam</option><option>Bihar</option><option>Chandigarh</option><option>Delhi</option><option>Goa</option><option>Haryana</option><option>Jammu and Kashmir</option><option>Kerala</option><option>Maharashtra</option><option>Punjab</option><option>Tamil Nadu</option><option>West Bengal</option></select><input name="phone" type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 272px; top: 323px; width: 240px; height: 27px;" maxlength="10"><input name="card" type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 274px; top: 375px; width: 235px; height: 30px;" maxlength="16"></span></p></div>');

    $("body").find(".mydiv:last").hide().slideDown("slow");
});
});
```

In this case, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmDtj/) would be most beneficial to understand what I want:

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FmDtj/3

```
.mydiv {position: relative;}
```

Comment: Super! However, in general, as @smb says, do I need to build up elements inside a `<div>` with `property:relative` or is it okay to simply make the outer `<div>` have that style?

Comment: You can see from my fiddle that it works to just set .mydiv to relative. An element that's absolutely-positioned is set relative to its nearest positioned ancestor. It's good practice to set a parent element to relative anyway.

Comment: So what I did was okay? One reason for doing so was that I'm using Dreamweaver and unless an element is absolutely positioned, you cannot simply drag it around and I'm on the shorter side of time!

Comment: It's ok, but I prefer to avoid absolute positioning. It makes for more and messier code, and the resulting pages don't tend to flow well with changes or for fluid/responsive sizing.

Comment: @isherwood you should use the proper positioning that works for the specific layout of your page with the least number of DOM elements, markup, and CSS, and not be beholden to any particular style. sometimes you really can't avoid using it, and sometimes it's just the best solution.

Comment: @isherwood I see. Is there something like Dreamweaver but with more inclination to drag-and-drop style? It wouldn't hurt if developing pages with Dreamweaver became a tad faster?

Comment: That's just an awful way to build a website. I can't recommend any such thing. Sorry. If you learn HTML/CSS you'll be much better off.

Comment: I'm aware that intricate knowledge of HTML/CSS will give you much better control than drag and drop and I do agree. However if you look at Dreamweaver, it does offer you an option to drag things about. By 'drag', I only mean that it allows you to change the co-ordinates visually.(isn't that faster than entering left,right,top..values and checking each time?) That's all the drag and drop aspect I wish I had. Any finer, and I'd do manual tuning myself.

Comment: Normal page design doesn't involve setting values for up/down/left/right. It involves creating semantic markup that can be styled as needed via CSS, but that works as well without CSS, and rarely needs absolute positioning. You don't need intricate knowledge. A basic understanding goes a long way. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

When you position the elements of your sliding div absolute the slide does not recognize them as elements part of your div.

Build up the content of the sliding div without absolute positioning and it will work.

Comment: If you set the 'div.myDiv' position to relative, you can still use absolute positioning inside your div and get the same effect. just an FYI.